# Get this month to next 5 months

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have 2 list elements.

From: (have to show this month to next 4 months) like

```
<li>October 2017</li> 
<li>November 2017</li>
<li>December 2017</li>
<li>January 2018</li>
<li>Febraury 2018</li>
```

To: (have to show 1 year from this month to past 4 months) like

```
<li>June 2018</li> 
<li>July 2018</li>
<li>August 2018</li>
<li>September 2018</li>
<li>October 2018</li>
```

Is it possible we can display this using Javascript or Jquery.

**JS:**

```
getFullMonth() {
    var month = new Array();
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";

    var d = new Date();
    var n = month[d.getMonth()];
    document.getElementById("fromDate").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Comment: `n = month[d.getMonth()+1];` `n = month[d.getMonth()+2];`, etc.;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using the [moment library](https://momentjs.com/) for date manipulation, it makes things nicer.

So you need to print a list of the next 5 months, including the current one. Then you want a second corresponding list that is `1 year - 4 months` ahead, or `+ 8 months` for simplicity.

```js
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {

  var dt = moment().add(i, 'months'); 

   $('<li />').text(dt.format('MMMM YYYY')).appendTo('#current')
   
   dt.add(8, 'months');
   
   $('<li />').text(dt.format('MMMM YYYY')).appendTo('#advanced')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<ul id="current"></ul>
<ul id="advanced"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use a `for` loop based on the current month and incrementing each iteration, and appending the `li` with the target month to the relevant `ul`, something like this:

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('.from').append(`<li>${months[(currentMonth + i) % months.length]}</li>`);
  
  $('.to').append(`<li>${months[(currentMonth + i + 8) % months.length]}</li>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="from"></ul>
<ul class="to"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```js
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {

  var dt = moment().add(i, 'months'); 

   $('<li />').text(dt.format('MMMM YYYY')).appendTo('#current')
   
   dt.add(8, 'months');
   
   $('<li />').text(dt.format('MMMM YYYY')).appendTo('#advanced')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<ul id="current"></ul>
<ul id="advanced"></ul>
```